# bash one-liner/script to execute a command on files that do not have an associated file

Tags: bash, find, xargs

The following executes `do_x.sh` on all files of type `a_???.json` recursively. However, I would like to do the same on a subset of these files that do not have a corresponding file with the same name and different extension.

```
 find $PWD -type f -name "a_???.json"  | xargs -I{} do_x.sh {}
```

How do I say in the same one-liner, do the same but only on the files `a_???.json` that do not have a corresponding `a_???.json` done? The following is not a solution for sure:

```
find $PWD -type f -name "a_???.json" -exclude "a_???.json.done" | xargs -I{} do_x.sh {}
```

```
Example
a_111.json
a_112.json
a_111.json.done
```

So, execute `do_x.sh` only on `a_112.json`

Comment: Can you put that logic into `do_x.sh`?

Comment: The intent is to skip sending them to compute nodes on cluster:   find $PWD -type f -name "a_???.json"  | xargs -I{} -n1 -P10 srun -N1 -A goc -p slurm do_x.sh {}

Comment: Asking for a one liner will discourage many people from trying to help you since it tells us you favor brevity over robustness, clarity, efficiency, portability, and everything else that actually matters in software and so are likely to accept the briefest answer rather than a good one. You might want to [edit] your subject line and description to remove "one liner" if you actually just want a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep the same structure of your script, try this :

```
find $PWD -type f -name "a_???.json" -execdir test '!' -f {}.done \; -print | xargs -I{} do_x.sh {}
```

Comment: How would this change if srun is added: find $PWD -type f -name "a_???.json" | xargs -I{} -n1 -P10 srun -N1 -A goc -p slurm do_x.sh {}

Comment: You don't actually need `bash -c` here, since `test` is available as an external command: `find "$PWD" -type f -name "a_???.json" -exec test '!' -f {}.done \; -print | xargs ...` (note: I single-quoted the exclamation mark to prevent bash from mistaking it for a history expansion). And @Tims none of these changes to the `find` command affect how you process the resulting file list with `xargs` and/or `do_x.sh` -- they *only* change the output of `find` to exclude files that have a corresponding .done file.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I noticed that yesterday, but didn't have time to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Execute a shell `if` statement in `xargs`.

```
find "$PWD" -type f -name "a_???.json" -exec bash -c 'if ! [ -f "$1.done" ]; then do_x.sh "$1"; fi' {} {} \;
```

There's no need to use `xargs`, you can use the `-exec` keyword to `find` to execute commands.

Since `-exec` doesn't use the shell to execute the command, you have to execute `bash -c` explicitly.

For your more complex command, it's similar. Use `xargs` to get the parallel operation, then put your full command in the `then` clause of `if`.

```
find "$PWD" -type f -name "a_???.json" | 
    xargs -I{} -n1 -P10 bash -c 'if ! [ -f "$1.done" ]; then srun -N1 -A goc -p slurm do_x.sh "$1"; fi' {} {} \;
```

Comment: What are the two {} {} for ?

Comment: I was hoping you wouldn't ask. In some versions of `bash`, the first argument after `-c <command>` becomes `$0`, so you need two of them to fill in `$1`. I was trying to find another question that answers this, but failed.

Comment: How would this change if srun is added: find $PWD -type f -name "a_???.json" | xargs -I{} -n1 -P10 srun -N1 -A goc -p slurm do_x.sh {}

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xargs` to run shell code via the command `bash -c`.  This allows you to process multiple `find` hits with the same command, which may provide a noticeable performance improvement if you have a lot of files:

```
find "$PWD" -type f -name "a_???.json" -print0 |
   xargs -0 -r bash -c 'for f; do [[ -e "${f}.done" ]] || do_x.sh "$f"; done' bash
```

I have split that across two lines for legibility, but it is a single pipeline.

Note that the `for` loop without explicit arguments items runs over the positional parameters, which is how the shell will receive the filenames from `find`.

Note also that the trailing `bash` is intentional and necessary, or at least *something* is necessary at that position, else the first fileame emitted by `find` will be consumed for use as the `$0` of the shell in which the command runs.

Comment: How would this change if srun is added: find $PWD -type f -name "a_???.json" | xargs -I{} -n1 -P10 srun -N1 -A goc -p slurm do_x.sh {}

Comment: @Tims, I don't see why the `srun` would make a particular difference itself.  It and all its arguments could be put into the `bash` command without issue.  But the `-P10` option to `xargs` is a different matter. The command presented here will run all the `do_sh` commands in sequence, just as the example presented in the question does.  If you want to parallelize with `-P` then the alternatives presented in other answers are better suited to your needs.